# Last Month to Date

Tags: sql

I am trying to calculate the **sales for last month to date**.

I have created the month to date as the following:

```
sum(case when year(s.bus_dat) = year(getdate()) and month(s.bus_dat) = month(getdate()) 
then qty_sold end) as MTD_SAL,
```

I need to create the last month to date in a similar way (I want the code represent the date from the beginning of last month til today so if today is `10/28/2018` I need to show all the sales from `09/01/2018` to `10/28/2018`

Any advice please?

Comment: can you figure out how to format your code? all your questions seem to have `enter code here` everywhere.  you're supposed to replace the placeholder text with your code so your code is nicely formatted in a fixed with typeface

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the first day of the month, then go back a month using this:

```
dateadd(m,-1,dateadd(d,-day(getdate())+1,getdate()))
```

Need to make sure its the start of the day, so convert to date:

```
convert(date,dateadd(m,-1,dateadd(d,-day(getdate())+1,getdate())))
```

So your complete columns becomes:

```
sum(case when s.bus_dat>=
  convert(date,dateadd(m,-1,dateadd(d,-day(getdate())+1,getdate())))) 
then qty_sold else 0 end) as LM
```

Comment: Great, thanks @BahaaGerges. Please remember to accept the answer to close off the question.

Answer (score 0):

To get something between last month and today you can use :

```
BETWEEN DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()),'-',MONTH(NOW()),'-01')) - INTERVAL 1 MONTH AND DATE()
```